# Slope of a logarithmic plot (Bode plot)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to know how to find the slope of a magnitude Bode plot at a certain frequency $\omega=\omega_c$ (the crossover frequency). This would be calculated as

$$n_{c}=\frac{d}{d\log(\omega)}\log(|P(i\omega)|)|_{\omega=\omega_c}$$

I have this case in particular.

$$P(i\omega)=0.875\frac{(1+i\omega)(2+i\omega)^2}{(i\omega)^2(-2+i\omega)}$$

So

$$\log(|P(i\omega)|)=\log(0.875)-2\log(\omega)+\log(\sqrt{1+\omega^2})+\log(\sqrt{4+\omega^2})$$

But I don't know how to derive that function respect to  the variable $\log(\omega)$. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
 $$\frac{dy}{d\log(\omega)}=\frac{dy}{d\omega}\times \frac{d\omega}{d\log(\omega)}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\omega}}{\frac{d\log(\omega)}{d\omega}}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\omega}}{\frac 1\omega}=\omega \times \frac{dy}{d\omega}$$